# Django admin editing fields in a tabular fashion

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with lots of say `CharField` fields, that I would like to edit in the admin.

The problem is that each field takes up one line. How should I make them display like this (horizontally):
[image: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/_images/admin12.png]
<sub>(source: [djangoproject.com](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/_images/admin12.png))</sub>

(they are not foreign keys)

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this one. Is my question not clear enough, or is what I am asking somehow undoable or irrelevant?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django 1.2 has ListEdit extension for the Admin

This is how you use it:

```
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ( 'Name','Type')
     list_editable = ( 'Type', )
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [v-lad.org](http://v-lad.org/Imgs/Django-ListEdit.png))</sub>

Comment: Is there a way of being able to add entries to that table without having to switch to a different page?